# With iText 5, how to save a PDF file as linearized PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

With iText 5 (java), is it possible to save a PDF file as a linearized PDF, also called sometimes “Web Optimized” or “Fast Web View” enabled PDF ?

Answer (score 1):

iText 5 does not have a feature for saving linearized PDFs.

Actually this would not fit the iText 5 architecture at all which attempts to write data to its target output stream as early as possible, and you cannot do that while creating a linearized PDF.

Nonetheless, you can of course create a `PdfStamper`-like class which takes a `PdfReader` representing an existing PDF and stores it as a linearized PDF. This will require quite some coding, though.